# Mocking android method in Junit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to create some JUnit tests for my Android app.

In the app I have the following method, which I am trying to get tested:

```
public void checkBoxAction(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
    Boolean isChecked = cb.isChecked();
    //Do stuff
}
```

I am using Mockito and I have got this far:

```
// ...
CheckBox dummyV = new CheckBox(mMockContext);
Mockito.when(dummyV.isChecked()).thenReturn(true);
item.checkBoxAction(dummyV);
// ...
```

But when I run the test I get error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method isChecked in
android.widget.CompoundButton not mocked...
```

I think the problem is that in the method `checkBoxAction`, the `isChecked` method is not executed on `v`, but on other object. Is this assumption correct? Is this the problem? And how can I fix it? Or there is something else?

Comment: Try `CheckBox dummyV = mock(CheckBox.class);`

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thanks!

Comment: ok, added as an answer. If it works please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock the `CheckBox` if you want to use `Mockito.when`, try:

```
CheckBox dummyV = mock(CheckBox.class);
```